# <Binary> in sql

Tags: c++, sql, .net, binary, c++-cli

I want to select all the binary data from a column of a SQL database (SQL Server Enterprise) using C++ query. I'm not sure what is in the binary data, and all it says is .
I tried this (it's been passed onto me to study off from) and I honestly don't 100% understand the code at some parts, as I commented):

```
SqlConnection^ cn = gcnew SqlConnection();
SqlCommand^ cmd;
SqlDataAdapter^ da;
DataTable^ dt;
cn->ConnectionString = "Server = localhost; Database=portable; User ID = glitch; Pwd = 1234";
cn->Open();
cmd=gcnew SqlCommand("SELECT BinaryColumn FROM RawData", cn);
da = gcnew SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dt = gcnew DataTable("BinaryTemp"); //I'm confused about this piece of code, is it supposed to create a new table in the database or a temp one in the code?
da->Fill(dt);
for(int i = 0; i < dt->Rows->Count-1; i++)
{
String^ value_string;
value_string=dt->Rows[i]->ToString();
Console::WriteLine(value_string);
}
cn->Close();
Console::ReadLine();
```

but it only returns a lot of "System.Data.DataRow".

Can someone help me?

(I need to put it into a matrix form after I extract the binary data, so if anyone could provide help for that part as well, it'd be highly appreciated!)

Comment: Try using a prepared function or treating the database as an I/O stream.

Comment: I edited so it now has the code with it.
@ThomasMatthews could you give me an example of it or give me a link to something more in detail?

Answer (score 0):

`dt->Rows[i]` is indeed a [`DataRow ^`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). To extract a specific field from it, use its indexer:

```
array<char> ^blob=dt->Rows[i][0];
```

This extracts the first column (since you have only one) and returns an array representation of it.

To answer the question in your code, the way `SqlDataAdapter` works is like this:

- you build a `DataTable` to hold the data to retrieve. You can fill in its columns, but you're not required to. Neither are you required to give it a name.
- you build the adapter object, giving it a query and a connection object
- you call the `Fill` method on the adapter, giving it the previously created `DataTable` to fill with whatever your query returns.
- and you're done with the adapter. At this point you can dispose of it (for example inside a `using` statement if you're using C#).

Comment: Thank you for your input! I am using C++.
I have two questions concerning what you said:
1. array<char> should replace String, right? 
2. Using Item[0], I got an error ''Item': use 'default' to access the default property (indexer) for class 'System::Data::DataRow''

Comment: Well it's a binary array instead of string, but you can get your string out using `Encoding::UTF8->GetString()`. I'll fix my code for the 2nd error, it's been a while. Basically instead of `->Item[]` you use `[]` directly.

Comment: I tried String ^value_string = dt->Rows[i][0]->ToString(); and now I get a continuous "System.Data[]". Using [] gives me a syntax error so I don't think I quite understand how you'd implement it, same for Encoding::UTF8->GetString(). It says 'Encoding':is not a class or namespace name, 'UTF8':undeclared identifier, left of '->GetString' must point to class/struct/union/generic type.

Comment: `DataRow->Item[int]` returns an object that's an array. You have to cast it to the array type to use its indexer (or any properties for that matter). `Encoding` is in `System::Text`. Both of these are trivially answered by simply googling the class name and reading the documentation.